# Prevent output for query --destination_table command

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to prevent screen output for the query --destination_table?

I wan to move data sets through the workflow, but not necessarily see the all the rows

bug on job_73d3dffab7974d9db360f5c31a3a9fa7

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, we'll fix it in the next version of bq. To work around, you can add `--max_rows=0`. This only changes the number of rows that get sent back, not the number of rows that get returned by the query (you can use `LIMIT N` for that in the query).

Comment: Did this ever get fixed? The same thing happens in the current version